# i install angular, when i am trying run with ng serve --open it is showing this error

Tags: angular

I get this error, running my code.

```
An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\college\COMP228-Project-main\COMP228-Project-main\client\node_modules\bootstrap'
See "C:\Users\konul\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-w279i5\angular-errors.log" for further details.
⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
```

Comment: Did you run npm install?

Comment: Did you see C:\Users\konul\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-w279i5\angular-errors.log for further details?

Comment: yes i run npm, but it is same error

Comment: Install node om your device

Comment: you have to run that command in the root folder (it is where you have your package.json file)

Comment: make sure that you are in the root folder and you did "npm install". The error states that the "bootstrap" folder does not exist in "node_modules", so most likely you didn't install it.

Answer (score 0):

use `cd "project folder name"` in terminal to access the project.